# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tb' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

While am running the Application, I got the error in the declaration of `constants.ts`(assigning the `json` file data to the constant variables.) file.

I declared some data in `json` file like `object.json.`

```
{
 "furniture": {
     "tb": {
         "value": "table",
         "display": "Table(s)"
      },
      "ch": {
        "value": "chair",
        "display": "Chair(s)"
     }
 },
 "furnitureTypes": [
    {
     "value": "LivingRoomSofa",
     "display": "Living Room Sofa"
    },
    {
     "value": "CoffeeTable",
     "display": "Coffee Table"
    },
   {
    "value": "AccentCabinet",
    "display": "Accent Cabinet"
   }
 ],
"boardes": [
      {
       "value": null,
       "display": "--"
      },
      {
       "value": "Blockboard",
       "display": "Block board"
      },
      {
       "value": "Foamboard",
       "display": "Foam board"
      },
      {
       "value": "Fiberboard",
       "display": "Fiber board"
      }
  ]
}
```

next, I created one constants.ts file in I import the above json file.

```
import * as objData from './objects.json';
```

In that constants.ts file

```
import * as objData from './objects.json';

const obj = <any>objData;

console.log('obj---:',obj);

export const Constants = { farr : [obj.furniture.tb, obj.furniture.ch]; }
```

Run the project and I got the error.

> Cannot read property 'tb' of undefined at Module../src/app/shared/constants.ts

This is the console log showes:

> obj-- Module {default: {…}, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}

why it is getting `Module` and added `default` key but actually it's shows direct  `json object data`.

what am saying that:
 I need like this showing `json object`.

```
json-obj----------: 
  {farr: Array(2),furnitureTypes: Array(3), boardes: Array(4), …}
   boardes: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  farr: (2) [{…}, {…}]
  furniture: {tb: {…}, ch: {…}}
  furnitureTypes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
  __proto__: Object
```

> Here i can direct access like `obj.tarr.a and obj.tripTypes[0]`

But In my scenario, in console log it showing like this:

```
obj---: 
 Module {default: {…}, __esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 
 "Module"}
default:
   boardes: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
   furniture: {tb: {…}, ch: {…}}
   furnitureTypes: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
   __proto__: Object
   Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
   __esModule: true
```

Here it is showing like `Module` not an `Object`.

> How can i get it as `Object`?

Can anyone help me out to solve the problem?

Comment: I am not seeing any error while setting up the code as per your explanation. Refer following stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgekfz?file=app/input-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create the file name with extension as **`.ts`** (example.ts) and in that **`example.ts`** file

```
export default {
  "furniture": {
    "tb": {
      "value": "tables",
      "display": "Table(s)"
    },
    "ch": {
      "value": "chairs",
      "display": "Chair(s)"
    }
  }
}
```

and you need to import this file in your component

```
import obj from './example';
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qdu4p2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

it will work as your expectation

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
But here the ``json(object.json file)`` data i import that file into ``constants.ts`` file. Am accessing the ``json`` data through the `constants.ts` file only. How can i access the `json` file data in `constants.ts` file.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are you saying

Comment: You are placed `json` data in `.ts` file right. what am saying that `json` data i kept in `.json`file only. That `.json` file i import in one `constants.ts` file. In that `import * as objData from './objects.json';constants.ts` file i placed `const obj = <any>objData;
export const Constants = { farr : [obj.furniture.tb, obj.furniture.ch]; }` then am getting the error of `tb undefiend`.

Comment: you need to change the file extension so that it will work as your expectation

Comment: Hi @ram12393, here am getting as the ``module`` type not an ``object`` type of the ``json`` file, and I hope that, i clearly mentioned in the above data, so please once check the my post and reply me where i did the mistake. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you please produce `stackblitz` url

Comment: In `stackblitz` am getting, what i need but when am compiling in my editor am getting the `deafult` key, so can i share my project `git repo` link?

Comment: Hi @ram12393, This is the `stackblitz url`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-owua6h, in this url i am getting how i need the data. It showing as a `Object`, but the same code when i run in the editor in the console it will showing as a `module`. I am not understand why it coming as `Module`. These we can get in `dev tools in console only.`